# Matplotlib Patches don't have "get_transform" attributes?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

I'm having trouble trying to map polygon objects onto a world map using matplotlib's PatchCollections (I'm also trying to color each polygon according to a statistic/value I have, but the error occurs before this, so I don't think it is relevant).

I imported matplotlib, PatchCollection, and others as so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
mpl.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gp
import shapely
```

My data is in a GeoPandas DataFrame called "poly_df".

(Note that I separated out each instance of Multipolygons so each polygon has its own row. For example, Norway has multiple rows in this dataframe rather than one row with a multipolygon in the geometry column, but my problem was occuring even before this.)

poly_df:

```
 countryname, value,  geometry 
 Norway,      10.031, POLYGON ((-9.0430908203125 70.80386352539062, ...
```

When I try to call PatchCollection, after doing things like drawing coastlines etc, like this:

```
patches = poly_df.geometry.tolist()
collection = PatchCollection(patches, zorder=5)
```

where each element in this "patches" list is:

```
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

I'm getting this error (geo_plot() is my function where all this is being done):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "labor_participation.py", line 125, in <module>
    geo_plot()
  File "labor_participation.py", line 109, in geo_plot
    collection = PatchCollection(patches, zorder=5)
  File "/Users/Martin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1696, in __init__
    self.set_paths(patches)
  File "/Users/Martin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1700, in set_paths
    for p in patches]
  File "/Users/Martin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1700, in <listcomp>
    for p in patches]
AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'get_transform'
```

Am I supposed to pass something into PatchCollection() other than the list of Polygon objects that I'm currently trying, and failing, to use? If Polygon objects don't have this attribute - what does? I could really use some guidance, I'm new to geographic data. Thank you.

Comment: As a possible alternative, you can create choropleth maps with geopandas http://geopandas.org/mapping.html#chloropleth-maps

Comment: Thank you, this is really good to know. I may resort to this if I can't figure out why my matplotlib PatchCollections error is occuring.

Comment: Matplotlib's `PatchCollection` does not support geometry objects like Polygons. You have to convert those to something matplotlib understands, and this is exactly what the built-in plotting machinery of geopandas does for you. If you really want to do it manually (which of course can be a good learning exercise), you can take a look at the geopandas source code: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/55d59ee7d5d2e103e46730c753e3740c159a6035/geopandas/plotting.py#L46-L106

Comment: I didn't quite understand how geopandas and matplotlib fit together, but seeing the sourcecode does help. I ended up using geopandas to plot it out. (I did actually ended up reinventing the _flatten_multi_geoms() function unintentionally at one point to try and fix this error!).

Thank you for the link and clarification, this makes more sense.